# Run Oracle DBCA with subprocess.check_call in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, oracle

I want to run Oracle DBCA to create a database in silent mode.
The command I want to run via Python script is the following one:

```
dbca -silent -createDatabase -templateName General_Purpose.dbc -gdbName testdb -sid testdb -createAsContainerDatabase false -emConfiguration NONE -datafileDestination /u01/data/oracle/testdb/db_files -storageType FS -characterSet AL32UTF8 -totalMemory 2048 -recoveryAreaDestination /u01/app/oracle/fast_recovery_area
```

If I run that command directly from the bash console it runs perfectly. Now I want to adapt it to be ran from a python script so I did the following:

```
subprocess.check_call(['dbca', '-silent', '-createDatabase', '-templateName', 'General_Purpose.dbc', '-gdbName', gdbName, '-sid', sid, '-createAsContainerDatabase', 'false', '-emConfiguration', 'NONE', '-datafileDestination', dfDest, '-storageType', storageType, '-characterSet', 'AL32UTF8', '-totalMemory', totalMemory, '-recoveryAreaDestination', recoAreaDest])
```

Not all of the arguments have single quotes and that's because I'm passing some variables as arguments.
My variables are the following ones:

```
#### VARIABLES ####
gdbName = ""
sid = ""
#dfDest = ""
storageType = "FS"
totalMemory = "2048"
recoAreaDest = oracle_base + "/fast_recovery_area"

#### USER INPUTS ####
while gdbName == "":
    gdbName = input("\n" + "Global DB name: ")
while sid == "":
    sid = input("SID: ")
dfDest = "/u01/data/oracle/" + sid + "/db_files"
dfDest = input("Datafile destination [" + dfDest + "]: ")
storageType = input("Storage type [" + storageType + "]: ")
totalMemory = input("Total Memory (in MB) [" + totalMemory + "]: ")
recoAreaDest = input("Fast recover area [" + recoAreaDest + "]: ")
```

So when I run my script the following error occurs:

```
[oracle@dataguard-test-primary ~]$ ./oracle_silent_install.py

1. Install Software
2. Create Database
     Option: 2


Oracle Database Creation script
Please enter the required info...


Global DB name: d
SID: d
Datafile destination [/u01/data/oracle/d/db_files]:
Storage type [FS]:
Total Memory (in MB) [2048]:
Fast recover area [/u01/app/oracle/fast_recovery_area]:
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at oracle.install.commons.swing.StandardDialog$ErrorDialogShowTask.call(StandardDialog.java:567)
        at oracle.install.commons.swing.StandardDialog$ErrorDialogShowTask.call(StandardDialog.java:516)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
[oracle@dataguard-test-primary ~]$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

At the user input section, when trying to just hit 'enter' to pick the default value, the variable was being replaced with the value *null* because it read nothing, so I added an *if* after each user input to verify if the user just hit *Enter* and then fill the variable again with the default value.